# How can I check if c-blosc is installed using the command line?

Tags: bash, command-line, homebrew

Using `command -v c-blosc` returns nothing, even though it's installed

c-blosc describes themselves as a [compression library](https://github.com/Blosc/c-blosc), so it's not a command

---

A few things I've tried

```
% c-blosc
zsh: command not found: c-blosc
where c-blosc
c-blosc not found
brew install c-blosc
...
Warning: c-blosc 1.21.0 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 1.21.0, run:
  brew reinstall c-blosc

% brew info c-blosc
c-blosc: stable 1.21.0 (bottled)
Blocking, shuffling and loss-less compression library
https://blosc.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/c-blosc/1.21.0 (10 files, 1.7MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2021-07-07 at 23:44:40
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/c-blosc.rb
License: BSD-3-Clause
==> Dependencies
Build: cmake ✘
==> Analytics
install: 312 (30 days), 1,190 (90 days), 3,168 (365 days)
install-on-request: 249 (30 days), 998 (90 days), 2,263 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)
brew search c-blosc 
==> Formulae
c-blosc ✔
```

---

The following

```
if [ brew info c-blosc 2>&1 >/dev/null ]; then
    echo "Installed"
else
    echo "Nope"
fi
```

and

```
if [ brew search c-blosc 2>&1 >/dev/null ]; then
    echo "Installed"
else
    echo "Nope"
fi
```

both print `Nope` even though I have it installed

Comment: What is the result of `brew search c-blosc 2>&1; echo $?`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/145437, you can just do

```
brew info c-blosc
```

That will print, among other things, the install location.
You can use related commands, like `search`:

```
brew search c-blosc
```

The only command explicitly [documented](https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage) to return a fail code for missing formulas is

```
brew --prefix --installed c-blosc
```

It has no output specifically so that you can do

```
if brew --prefix --installed c-blosc 2>/dev/null; then
    echo "Installed"
else
    echo "Nope"
fi
```

Comment: I updated my question to include the result of this answer, I tried `brew search c-blosc` instead of `brew info c-blosc` and if also returned false

Comment: @Sam. I've added an update based on a more careful reading of the docs and your findings

Comment: @Sam. You were on the right track. However `$(...)` gets the stdout of a command, not the return code. My mistake was wrapping the command in `test`, a.k.a. `[ ... ]`. Thanks for the catch. I've fixed the problem now

Comment: @Sam. By the way, does something like this work: `brew info c-blosc 2>&1 >/dev/null && echo "Installed" || echo "Nope"`? If it does, then my original answer was essentially correct, and the mistake was to use `[ ... ]` as you caught for me earlier.

Comment: That does not work, with the way the answer is now it works, but when it's not installed an error prints to the console. `if [ $(brew --prefix --installed c-blosc 2>/dev/null)  ]; then
    echo "Installed"
else
    echo "Nope"
fi` was the best answer, that performs correctly and doesn't have any other output, and performs the same on `bash` `zsh` and `sh`

Comment: @Sam. Updated. Thanks for testing for me. I know bash but never worked on a Mac or used brew

Comment: @Sam. I think I suppressed stdout in my latest

Comment: Put it inside `$()`

Comment: @Sam. I think you're missing the point of `$(...)`. It's the captured stdout of a subshell. You want the return code, so no capturing needed. Unless I'm the one missing the point

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `$(...)` is needed or else it doesn't work

Comment: @Sam. `brew --prefix --installed` is specifically designed to use a return code, not stdout. The shell construct `$()` grabs stdout and ignores the return code. `if command` without brackets or anything else checks the return code of `command`.

Answer (score 1):

As the `c-blosc` package doesn't include any commands, you won't find if it is installed using either of these:

```
command c-blosc
type c-blosc
```

The package actually provides a dynamic link library and a header file, which you can see by using the following command to list the package contents:

```
brew ls c-blosc

/usr/local/Cellar/c-blosc/1.21.0/include/ (2 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/c-blosc/1.21.0/lib/libblosc.1.21.0.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/c-blosc/1.21.0/lib/pkgconfig/blosc.pc
/usr/local/Cellar/c-blosc/1.21.0/lib/ (3 other files)
```

Now **homebrew** creates symbolic links in `/usr/local/lib` for you to link your programs against - let's look:

```
ls -l /usr/local/lib/*blosc*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 mark  admin  50 14 Jul 07:52 /usr/local/lib/libblosc.1.21.0.dylib -> ../Cellar/c-blosc/1.21.0/lib/libblosc.1.21.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 mark  admin  45 14 Jul 07:52 /usr/local/lib/libblosc.1.dylib -> ../Cellar/c-blosc/1.21.0/lib/libblosc.1.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 mark  admin  39 14 Jul 07:52 /usr/local/lib/libblosc.a -> ../Cellar/c-blosc/1.21.0/lib/libblosc.a
lrwxr-xr-x  1 mark  admin  43 14 Jul 07:52 /usr/local/lib/libblosc.dylib -> ../Cellar/c-blosc/1.21.0/lib/libblosc.dylib
```

So, the most generic of these, which will exist regardless of version, is `libblosc.dylib`, so I would use this as my test:

```
if [ -e /usr/local/lib/libblosc.dylib ] ; then echo "Installed" ; fi
```

---

Note that you *could* test more explicitly for that file existing **and being a symlink** with `if [ -L ... ]` but that *may* not work if `liblosc` is installed by some non-symbolic-linking method, e.g. from source which may copy an actually library to that location rather than making a symlink.

---

Another, alternative command that would work is the following which shows you where a given **homebrew** package is installed:

```
brew --prefix --installed c-blosc
/usr/local/opt/c-blosc
echo $?
0
```

As opposed to:

```
brew --prefix --installed MadeUpNonExistentPackage
Error: No available formula with the name "madeupnonexistentpackage".
echo $?
1
```